# GO REST Endpoint for File Uploads But Not Using ParseMultipartForm

Tags: curl, go

Newbie here. I'm trying to build a web server with a RESTful API so that I can test a curl command for file uploads. I was able to create the web server and an endpoint for file uploads.

Here is my upload endpoint:

```
func Upload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(MAX_MEMORY); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusForbidden)
    }

    fmt.Println("Endpoint hit: Upload")

    for key, value := range r.MultipartForm.Value {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s:%s ", key, value)
        log.Printf("%s:%s", key, value)
    }

    for _, fileHeaders := range r.MultipartForm.File {
        for _, fileHeader := range fileHeaders {
            file, _ := fileHeader.Open()
            path := fmt.Sprintf("files/%s", fileHeader.Filename)
            buf, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
            ioutil.WriteFile(path, buf, os.ModePerm)
            log.Println(http.StatusOK, fmt.Sprintf("file %s has been uploaded", fileHeader.Filename))
        }
    }
}
```

This endpoint works with the following curl command:

```
curl -F 'data=@/path/to/file/foo.tar.gz' localhost:8080/upload
```

However, this curl command does not:

```
curl -f -s -S -T /path/to/file/foo.tar.gz http://localhost:8080/upload
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

I need help creating an endpoint that will accept

```
curl -f -s -S -T /path/to/file/foo.tar.gz http://localhost:8080/upload
```

Thank you.

Edit: Here is my routes.go file.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

type Routes []Route

func NewRouter() *mux.Router {
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    for _, route := range routes {
        router.
        Methods(route.Method).
        Path(route.Pattern).
        Name(route.Name).
        Handler(route.HandlerFunc)
    }

    return router
}


var routes = Routes{
    Route{
        "Index",
        "GET",
        "/",
        Index,
    },
    Route{
        "Upload",
        "POST",
        "/upload",
        Upload,
    },
}
```

Comment: Are you using `net/http.ServeMux` or are you using some other 3rd party router that needs a method specified when registering handlers? Would be helpful if you show the code where you setup the router.

Comment: @mkopriva I am using "github.com/gorilla/mux"

Comment: @shellter I am running the curl commands via bash. I need to build an endpoint to test a shell script.

Comment: when registering the handler or configuring the gorilla router did you specify the http methods allowed?

Comment: @mkopriva I added my routes.go file. That's where I specified my routes including the upload route.

Comment: Ok, change POST to PUT, because curl documentation on `-T` says "If this is used on an HTTP(S) server, the PUT command will be used".

Comment: Ok, I changed the method to PUT. Now I get this error: 
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
How do I send back a response from the server?

Comment: By writing to `w`. E.g. `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)` will respond with 200 and empty body, if you need to send some content in the response body you can use `w.Write` either by itself or with the help of the `io` or `fmt` package, depending on what data you want to send back.

Comment: @mkopriva No, I dont think that I am. I'm not sure how to send one back.

Comment: for example look here https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/#tmp_3 how `fmt.Fprintf` is used to send a string back to the client.

Comment: Ok, Ill give it a shot and let you know!

Comment: So, I added w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK) and I get this new error in my logs: `2017/11/21 09:35:44 request Content-Type isn't multipart/form-data
Endpoint hit: Upload
2017/11/21 09:35:44 http: panic serving [::1]:58918: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

Comment: It panics because your function continues even after this line `http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusForbidden)`, if parsing multipart form fails you should send the error, as you are doing, but after that you should `return` from your handler to not execute the subsequent code.

Comment: Added a return in the error block and I get a forbidden, which is expected. Is there another method of uploading that is not multipart?

Comment: Well if `curl -T` isn't sending the body as multipart then it's probably an octet-stream, in which case it should be enough to write the request body directly to a file. But nothing stops you from first checking the request headers, then dumping the request body and checking its format and depending on that info deciding on how to handle the upload. Also your Upload handler is ignoring almost all errors, that is not ok, your handler should **at least** look something like this https://play.golang.org/p/yrv640Vzfz.

Comment: So your saying read the file in with something like io.ReadFull and then write it out to a file on disk, correct?

Comment: I've added an aswer that shows how you can write the request body with `io.Copy` which should be generally a more efficient approach than `io.ReadFull`. Also don't forget to `Sync` and `Close` the file as I did in the first version of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `curl -f -s -S -T /path/to/file/foo.tar.gz http://localhost:8080/upload` without any additional options that would set the content type, if there are such options (i'm not sure, my curl knowledge is almost non existent), you are sending a request with minimal headers, none of them indicating the type of the content.

For example logging the `r.Header` will print something like this:

```
map[Accept:[*/*] Content-Length:[18] Expect:[100-continue] User-Agent:[curl/7.54.0]]
```

This means that all that multipart code in your `Upload` handler is simply not necessary.

---

The content of the body is what you want, so you can use `io.Copy` to store that body into a file.

```
func Upload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    f, err := os.Create("filename")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    if _, err := io.Copy(f, r.Body); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := f.Sync(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "upload done...")
}
```

Since you're using `curl -f -s -S -T ...` the `Upload` handler does not know what the name, nor the type, of the file being uploaded is, you will have to generate a random name, or a timestamp name, or whatever in order to be able to create and store more than just one file.

You could also pass some of the file info (name, type) in the query parameters but i'm not sure if that satisfies your requirements. E.g.

```
curl -f -s -S -T /path/to/file/foo.tar.gz http://localhost:8080/upload?name=foo.tar.gz
```